# How to get the Name of an application setting in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

In application setting of visual c#, we can create a series of settings with specific Name, Type, Scope and Value. I have access to the value by the code:

```
string color= Myproject.Properties.Settings.Default.mycolor;
```

How can I get "mycolor", which is the name of this setting, in the output?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to retrieve the property name from the setting value (e.g. "blue") or using the setting accessor ("mycolor" property)?

Comment: I wanted to get "mycolor" and not the value. I resolved it by creating a dictionary with the key "mycolor" so I could find the key by value.
I had series of these settings so I found dictionary the best for my application. I am fairly new to C#, so there might be some other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the name of the setting, then you are looking to get the property name. In the book [Metaprogramming in .NET](http://www.manning.com/hazzard/), Kevin Hazzard has a routine that looks something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a property name string from a lambda expression to avoid the need
/// to hard-code the property name in tests.
/// </summary>
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

To call it you would do this:

```
string propertyName = GetPropertyName(() => Myproject.Properties.Settings.Default.mycolor);
```

I've added a static reflection utility to some of my projects to allow for access to this and other tools.

**EDIT**

With July 20, 2015 being set as the RTM date for Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6, this seems like a good time for an update.

Happily, all of my above code goes away in C# 6 (.NET 4.6) since there is a new nameof expression that takes care of this very easily now:

```
string propertyName = nameof(Myproject.Properties.Settings.Default.mycolor);
```

Some of the new features are described on the [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).

Comment: Has  has only the value, so the string color, he seems not to have access to `Settings.Default.mycolor`. Otherwise the question would be pretty pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my understanding of your requirement:

- You need to know the setting-name from an object
- f.e. you want to get `"mycolor"` from a color like `"Red"`(presuming that this is the default-value)

You can use the [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingspropertycollection(v=vs.110).aspx) collection and `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`:

```
var colorProperty = Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<System.Configuration.SettingsProperty>()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => color.Equals(p.DefaultValue)); // color f.e "Red"
string nameOfProperty = null;
if (colorProperty != null)
    nameOfProperty = colorProperty.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

A little extension method will help you out here:

```
public static string GetSettingName<TObject, TProperty>(this TObject settings, 
    Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> member) 
    where TObject : System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)member.Body;
    return expression.Member.Name;
}
```

And it's usage:

```
var settingName = Properties.Settings.Default.GetSettingName(s => s.mycolor);
```

Comment: If i understand the question OP has only the color, for example "red" and he wants to know the relevant setting-name. It would be pretty pointless to get `mycolor` if he already needs to use `s.mycolor`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: OP states *I have access to the value by the code* (see example) and asks *How can I get "mycolor", which is the name of this setting*. I'm still reading that as "give me the setting property name as a string [using reflection]." I do agree that it's useless, OP could just type "mycolor" somewhere.

Comment: He has access to the _value_ which is the color. However, maybe i've misunderstood it.

Comment: From your answer I see where you're coming from. You're translating the setting value back to the setting name, whereas I interpreted it as given the property accessor, give me the property name. I have asked OP to clarify.